# Boot Debian netinst CD to RAM?

Tags: debian, boot, livecd, debian-installer

Is it possible to boot an install CD to RAM?

I want to boot the CD and eject it before I proceed with the setup.

And when not, where do the changes have to be made, to get a "toram" boot option?

Comment: The Debian installer is always booted to RAM because it essentially consists of a kernel and initramfs.

Comment: @Celada I want to boot the cd and eject it before I proceed with the setup.

Comment: Yes, you can do that — precisely because the installer is all in RAM.

Comment: OK, I start the installer and after language selection I got no options to install. So first step is: "Detect and mount CD-ROM". So now second step: "Load installer componts from CD". Everything marked and loaded. But even now, when I start partitioning, the installer loads something from the cd. I would like to start "expert install from ram" in the boot loader, the cd gets loaded to ram (like grml does), ejects, and from there everything runs from the ram disk. Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems impossible to copy base packages from boot media to RAM to build an alternative APT repository for installation with current [Debian Installer](https://www.debian.org/devel/debian-installer/).

But you might be able to eject the media after boot and continue installation using "netboot" image which would download *everything* from the internet, not out of boot media.  You can remove it permanently once the netboot installer gets started.  You will be requested to configure networking at the very early step of the whole installation process.

You can find netboot ISO as `mini.iso` in the folder like  http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/ of the offcial repository.
It's quite small in size compared to other installer images like "netinst".